# I can get dates from API, but when i populate cell, my count is nil

Tags: ios, swift, rest, service, urlsession

I have the Service that have method that return in completion with async way the result, i can see the result in closure, but when i exit from closure my result is nil

I use Swift 5 for that, and use URLSession

```swift
var categoryViewModel = CategoryViewModel()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        navigationItem.title = "Digital Space"
        setupTableView()
        bindViewModel()
    }

    fileprivate func bindViewModel() {
        categoryViewModel.fetchCategories { (categories) in
            self.categoryViewModel.categories = categories
        }
    }
```

```swift
var categories: [Category]?

    mutating func fetchCategories(completion: @escaping ([Category]) -> ()) {
        var this = self
        Repository.getAllCategories { (result) in
            switch result {
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error)
            case .success(let categories):
                this.categories = categories
                completion(categories)
            }
        }
```

In Bind view model i put the breakpoint in self.categoryViewModel and i can get the dates from API, but when i exit from this method, and cellForRow for example, my categories from view model is nil.

Answer (score 0):

To solve that you can see that this calling is all async, this problem is from GCD

So to solve just make like that

swift

```
fileprivate func bindViewModel() {
        categoryViewModel.fetchCategories { (categories) in
            self.categoryViewModel.categories = categories
            DispatchQueue.Main.Async {
               self.tableView.reloadData()
           }
        }
    }
```